# Летающий fab в нижнем правом углу

Tags: java, android, button

Как сделать чтобы float action button летал в нижнем правом углу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Летал всмысле чтобы был над всей информацией на экране.

Comment: Что значит `летал`?

Comment: Видимо имеется ввиду, чтобы FAB можно было "таскать" пальчиком по экрану в любое место

Comment: Покажите вашу текущую разметку xml. И как он отображается сейчас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйте компонент `FloatingActionButton`.
Добавьте его в разметку, например вот так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp" />
```

Затем инициализируйте его в `Activity`:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Comment: очевидно это "решение" не решает проблемы в вопросе - *"чтобы был над всей информацией на экране"*